# Does $\pi \left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)=\pi\left(\sqrt{xy}\right)$ hold for infinitely many values of $x$ and $y$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The problem is (assume $\pi(x)$ to be the prime-counting function),

> Does there exist infinitely many solutions to the equality $\pi
> \left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)=\pi\left(\sqrt{xy}\right)$ with $x>y$ ?

In other words,

> Is it true that if $x>y$ then for all sufficiently large $x$ and $y$  we nust have $\pi
> \left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)>\pi\left(\sqrt{xy}\right)$ ?

If the answer to the first question is not affirmative then can an explicit lower bound be obtained for $\min(x,y)$.

I believe that an answer to both questions exists in literature but till now I have not found any.

So, it would be great if some references be given. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not only are there infinitely many solutions, but it's easy to find infinitely many solutions with $x-y = c$ for arbitrary $c$.  The point is that $\pi(x)$ doesn't change at all except at primes, so there are arbitrarily long stretches where $\pi$ is constant.

Comment: Well the AM-GM inequality gives us that $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $$\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \geqslant \bigg(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k\bigg)^{1/n}.$$ So perhaps if we apply the function $\pi$ to both sides, the inequality remains implied? The AM-GM inequality has equality iff (if and only if) $a_1 = a_2 =\cdots a_k$ so perhaps if $x = y$, we have equality and infinitely many solutions? This looks a bit... well... extraneous I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x=y+1$ then $\pi((x+y)/2)=\pi(y)=\pi(\sqrt{xy})$